# Evaluate returning #VALUE? when trying to calculate large VSTACK

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, office365, microsoft-excel-365

I am working on a project that is pulling a bunch of spilled data across a ton of sheets that are all in the same spot as the sheets are based off of a template.

Using the name manager I was able to create a function to evaluate an automatically forming text join to create a VSTACK formula with the spilled data from all of the sheets.

When copy/pasting the text from this text join, and calculating it normally, it has everything working, which means it’s not a problem with the calculation. But having this many different variables is causing the =Eval(my name manager formula for =EVALUATE(x)) to not work. After investigation I found that Name Manager formula's have a character limit of around 250, so I had created a UDF Formula using this code.

```
Public Function eval(ByVal str As String) As Variant
  eval = Application.Evaluate(str)
End Function
```

Although UDFs are supposed to calculate up to around 8000 characters, it still couldn t calculate my text join(around 4000 characters). Is there a way to make this work or have a version of evaluate that can process more? VBA solutions are absolutely on the table, let me know.

example of the text that is trying to be evaluated:

=VSTACK(Sheet1!A1#:Sheet1!G1#, Sheet2!A1#:Sheet2!G1#, Sheet3!A1#:Sheet3!G1#,etc…)

Also I have done a good amount of experimenting but for some reason excel wont let me do something like =VSTACK(Sheet95:Sheet100!A1#:G1#). Any feedback on why would be great as this would be a far simpler solution to the issues I'm facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
=REDUCE(EXPAND("",1,7,""),{"Sheet1";"Sheet2";"Sheet3"},LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,INDIRECT(b&"!A1#"):INDIRECT(b&"!G1#"))))
```

List of sheets can be prepared separately and passed as a name.
You can also make a list in a sheet and refer to it as a range of cells e.g. `E5:E7` or `E5:G5`, or `E5#` if it is a dynamic range. You can also call the UDF function, which returns a list of sheet names `MyList()`.
Initial row is now empty, but you can put some headers in it.
3D notation is not accepted here, because it would have to be something like this:

```
=VSTACK((Sheet95:Sheet100!A1#):(Sheet95:Sheet100!G1#))
```

and such operations on 3D ranges are impossible.

Comment: How would I go about making this dynamic, the list of sheets will be changing as new sheets are added and removed. I have a formula to list the sheets, and I can use text joins to format them as required but I am unable to evaluate(with both name manager evaluate and UDF evaluate) a text joined version of the formula. I currently have 3 cells being combined:
_
REDUCE(EXPAND("",1,7,""),{ _
"Sheet1";"Sheet2";"Sheet3";"Sheet4" _
},LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,INDIRECT(b&"!A1#"):INDIRECT(b&"!G1#"))))
_
The sheets are dynamic based on the actual sheet lists, but the full formula wont get evaluated.

Comment: You need a list with the names of the sheets. You can generate this list dynamically, and you can give it a name and use that name in the formula. You can create a list using the UDF function.
How to do it in detail depends on whether it will be all the sheets in the workbook or selected ones, I don't know.

Comment: I have created the dynamic array with the sheets that I want to be included, how would I integrate it into the formula you had provided? The list I am using was created with the name manager and spills the names, or should I create a text joined named list instead of a spilled named list?

Comment: It should be a list, not a text joining names. I completed my answer.